# Series Summation,Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

[image]

[image]

I am stuck on the 4 th one.I have done the rest.I have found out the value of a_n.But not getting how to proceed for the 4 th one.

Comment: May I ask where you got this question from? ^_^
(It seems like a good resource to practice from.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Split the summation, so $$S=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{13}}\Big(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}b_n x^n-\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}c_n x^n\Big)$$ But, now, notice that $b_n=\alpha^n$ and $c_n=\beta^n$. So the expression write $$S=\frac{1}{\sqrt{13}}\Big(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\alpha^n x^n-\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\beta^n x^n\Big)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{13}}\Big(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(\alpha x)^n -\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(\beta x)^n \Big)$$ in which you recognize $something$.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: the splitting you did is, according to the expression given by the OP, in two **divergent** series...

Comment: @Timbuc. Don't you agree with the last expression ? I am really interested by some discussion with you on this question. Thanks.

Comment: I agree with all the algebra, yet observe that each splitted sum is a geometric one which won't converge *unless* the ratio is less than one in absolute value. If each is taken in such a way that $$|\alpha^nx^n|<1$$ then I think everything is fine.

Comment: I am glad to see that, once more, I agree with your comments ! Cheers :-)